# VBS in HTA cannot find specific file but Batch can

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, hta

I have a HTA to do some tasks, this sub is for manipulating some local directories. When I run this line:

```
oShell.run "rename ""C:\DSS\Scanbay\Data"" ""DataX"""
```

it doesnt work, naturally I  have defined oShell ect...

When I run this line as a batch file:

```
rename "C:\DSS\Scanbay\Data" "DataX"
```

it works fine!

I cannot figure out why the vbs returns file not found error, any help please?

Comment: Try `oShell.Run "cmd /c rename ""C:\DSS\Scanbay\Data"" ""DataX""` instead. You might find [SS64 on VBScript '.Run'](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html) useful. The [`.ShellExecute`](https://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html) method might also be of interest.

Comment: The `RENAME` command is an internal cmd.exe command so if you are not explicitly within a batch file or at a cmd prompt you will need to specifiy the use of `CMD /C` within your vbscript as @JeffZeitlin has pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, `rename` is a CMD-builtin command, not an external program that you can invoke directly. You can invoke it via CMD, though:

```
oShell.Run "cmd /c rename ""C:\DSS\Scanbay\Data"" ""DataX"""
```

With that said, a better approach to renaming files or folders would be using the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set d = fso.GetFolder("C:\DSS\Scanbay\Data")
d.Name = "DataX"
```